# What is the regular expression for not word and not whitespace?

Tags: regex, python-regex

\W represents not word characters and [^\s] this can use as not whitespace but I want both.

```
Example: 
1. "A:3,B-4 C-A/9"
Ans:
A = 3
B = 4
C = A/9
2. "A:3,B-4/C C:A/9"
A = 3
B = 4/C
C = A/9
```

Comment: `\W` is not a word. `\S` is not a whitespace. `[^\w\s]` is not either. What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is how you are phrasing your regex pattern.  Consider the following find all approach:

```py
inp = "A:3,B-4 C-A/9"
matches = re.findall(r'[A-Z]+[:-]([^\s,]+)', inp)
print(matches)  # ['3', '4', 'A/9']
```

The regex pattern used above says to match:

- `[A-Z]+` leading uppercase letter term
- `[:-]` followed by either a colon or hyphen separator
- `([^\s,]+)` a non whitespace term excluding comma (capture it)

Comment: actually the character after 'A'/'B'/'C' can be anything which are not word (\W) ..but not word (\W) itself contains whitespace...I am expecting an answer where I can use all the caracters which are not word (\W) and also not space
btw thanks for your answer